# appending via Ajax to .closest() parent not working jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm commenting an specific post from a list. This is why I'm using `.closest()` parent.

**JQUERY**

```
    $('.comment').on('click', function(){ 
    var parent = $(this).closest('.post');

            $(document).CommentButton(id_user,comment);

        });
```

**FUNCTION** The comments posts via Ajax and retrieve a value....

```
        jQuery.fn.CommentButton=function(id_user,comment){
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "comment.php",
        data:   {
                    "comment":comment,
                    "id_user":id_user,
                },
        success: function(data) {
                            //alert(data)
                parent.find(".container").append(comment);//problem     
                                }

                });
        }
```

**HTML** I choose a random post to comment from the list.

```
            <ul>
            <li class="post"></li>
            <li class="post"></li>
            <li class="post">
                <div class="container"></div>
                    <button class="comment"></button>
            </li>
            <li class="post"></li>
            </ul>
```

**PROBLEM**

I cant append the comment in its specific container of his parent. How should I do that?

Comment: Seems like you need to read about [basics of variable scopes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

Comment: How do I declare `$(this)` outsid of the function?

Comment: Like so: `var that = $(this);` Basically, you declare it at the beginning of a function. Then if later you have to use $(this) inside of another scope, you can use `that` which points to the first time you made a reference to it. JavaScript now has `let` instead of `var` so look into @Jeto’s advice.

Comment: Yes I declared the variable...I suppressed the `var` and now works well. thank you.